# Splitting a dataframe into a specific number

Tags: r

My task at hand is to figure out how to split a data frame based on the cumulative sum of a column.

As an example, here is a data frame

df <- data.frame(a1 = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5",
"X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10"),
a2 = rnorm(20, mean=5, sd=2) )

df2 <- df[order(df$a2),] # the df is sorted from by a2 from smallest to largest.

How do I create a list of data frames where the a2 column sums to 10 in each df2 without any rows repeating?

Comment: This is not an easy combinatorial problem. Must it be equal to 10 (to some degree of accuracy) or is there some leeway?

Comment: Could you show us an expected output? That would make it easier to understand what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Some of the rows are already greater than ten, and in almost any sample you run from the given example, any two rows will add to more than 10.  So are you looking to split every time the sum gets to greater than 10?

Comment: Yep @AllanCameron - correct, once the sum gets > 10 it splits that database. In my original post I missed an important component - the df is ordered by a2 from smallest to largest (edited my original question; and made draws from the norm more realistic to my question)

Answer (score 1):

The result for each row depends on the value of previous rows, so requires an iterative approach. It may be easiest to wrap this in a function:

```r
split_sum <- function(data, column, split_by = 10) {

  x <- data[[as.character(match.call()$column)]]

  group <- current_group <- value <- 0
  
  for(i in seq(nrow(data))) {
    group[i] <- current_group
    value <- x[i] + value
    if(value > split_by) {
      current_group <- current_group + 1
      value <- 0
    }
  }
  
  setNames(split(data, group), NULL)
}
```

Testing this out, we have:

```r
df <- data.frame(a1 = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5",
                        "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10"), 
                 a2 = sort(rnorm(20, mean = 10, sd = 2)))

split_sum(df, a2, 10)
#> [[1]]
#>   a1       a2
#> 1 X1 6.232476
#> 2 X2 7.466659
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   a1       a2
#> 3 X3 7.674123
#> 4 X4 7.946872
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   a1       a2
#> 5 X5 8.202970
#> 6 X6 8.340281
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   a1       a2
#> 7 X7 9.046769
#> 8 X8 9.323847
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>     a1       a2
#> 9   X9 9.569602
#> 10 X10 9.955981
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>    a1       a2
#> 11 X1 10.58773
#> 
#> [[7]]
#>    a1       a2
#> 12 X2 10.69006
#> 
#> [[8]]
#>    a1      a2
#> 13 X3 10.7256
#> 
#> [[9]]
#>    a1       a2
#> 14 X4 11.61281
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>    a1       a2
#> 15 X5 11.80578
#> 
#> [[11]]
#>    a1       a2
#> 16 X6 11.91369
#> 
#> [[12]]
#>    a1       a2
#> 17 X7 12.40917
#> 
#> [[13]]
#>    a1       a2
#> 18 X8 13.11021
#> 
#> [[14]]
#>    a1       a2
#> 19 X9 14.00975
#> 
#> [[15]]
#>     a1       a2
#> 20 X10 14.11547
```

But the function is written in such a way as, for example, to break only when the sum reaches 50:

```r
split_sum(df, a2, 50)
#> [[1]]
#>   a1       a2
#> 1 X1 6.232476
#> 2 X2 7.466659
#> 3 X3 7.674123
#> 4 X4 7.946872
#> 5 X5 8.202970
#> 6 X6 8.340281
#> 7 X7 9.046769
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>     a1        a2
#> 8   X8  9.323847
#> 9   X9  9.569602
#> 10 X10  9.955981
#> 11  X1 10.587733
#> 12  X2 10.690059
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    a1       a2
#> 13 X3 10.72560
#> 14 X4 11.61281
#> 15 X5 11.80578
#> 16 X6 11.91369
#> 17 X7 12.40917
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>     a1       a2
#> 18  X8 13.11021
#> 19  X9 14.00975
#> 20 X10 14.11547
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>